# Jquery Plug with present Hebrew string as Question Marks

Tags: jquery, utf-8, hebrew

I'm using Jquery PlugIn, and I've changed string in the body of the .js file to Hebrew and this string represent as Question Marks in small black triangles.  the rest of the hebrew in the page works just fine.
Any Ideas?

Comment: not enough information. What jQuery plugin are you using? What is the context of the string? What happens to it in this plugin? Really need to see it in action and/or see some code.